# What is the best way to interrupt select, Linux?

Tags: c, linux, select, posix

I have to write a TCP server in C, Linux. I have a thread that listens on the open sockets to incoming requests with select() function. I have to interrupt the thread from time to time for a few things: add a new socket to the FD, close the FD etc.
I know there are two ways to wakeup the select() manually:

1. local socket that its FD is added to the set like implemented [here](http://www.binarytides.com/multiple-socket-connections-fdset-select-linux/).
2. self pipe trick like described [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-self-pipe-trick-explained/)

Can anyone please advise me what better to use?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to awake waiting thread? For termination? It might be a good idea to just use `pselect` or `signalfd` plus `select`. If you want to awake it for some other reason from another thread, you can use `eventfd`.

Comment: Also to avoid your question being flagged as "too broad" or "opinion based" I would recommend rephrasing it to something like "What is the best way to interrupt `select`?" and adding more information about what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Note that epoll is far more efficient than select and thread safe.

Comment: Maybe let select() time out and then re-start it? Another solution is to start a new thread for each accepted connection, or just have a pool of worker threads handling each accepted connection.